# I have created a login page. How to send these login parameters over to the server for validation and get the result back?

Tags: android

```
EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
EditText passWord = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
String user=userName.getEditableText().toString();
String pass=passWord.getEditableText().toString();
```

what to do after this?

Comment: open a http connection and post these parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class. The documentation describes the steps to connect to a server and receive a response. Be aware that network connections take time and you should not do this on the UI thread. You should start a worker thread to do the validation and put up some sort of "busy" notice on the UI thread. The article [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) has lots of info about this.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.my-site.com/auth_user.php?username="+username+"&pwd="+pwd);
    URLConnection authCustomerConn = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(authCustomerConn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    String res = "";
    if ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        res += inputLine;
    in.close();        
    Integer success = Integer.valueOf(res);
    // check if succeed
    ...
```

And don't forget to implement auth_user.php on your server :)